# Split String to get an Array

Tags: laravel

In Database :- "["http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg","http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg"]"

After Json_decode = ["http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg","http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg"]

Output i Want:- [0] - http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg
[1] - http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg

Code:-

```
   @if(is_array(json_decode($data->item_image)))
                                    @php $image = json_decode($data->item_image);
                                    @endphp
                                            @foreach($image as $key=>$row)
                                                @if($key == 0)
                                                <div class='carousel-item active'>
                                                    <!-- <img class='img-size img-responsive' src="{{ asset('image/'. $row) }}" /> -->
                                                    <img class='img-size img-responsive' src="{{ $row }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                @else
                                                <div class='carousel-item'>
                                                    <!-- <img class='img-size' src="{{ asset('image/'. $row) }}" /> -->
                                                    <img class='img-size' src="{{ $row }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                    @else

                                    @endif
```

Comment: are you getting an array of strings as json response ?

Comment: Yes after json_decode i'm getting a string

Comment: I'm kinda confused, looks like you're already getting an array of Strings?
You could break apart the string by doing stringName.split(",").

For ex:
String longString = "zyzabcstring.jpg,string2.jpg,string3.jpg";
 String[] strings = longString.split(",");

Comment: use explode function

Comment: add your code, so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: First i'm Checking it's an array but it can't go inside loop after var_dump output is string(133) - ["http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg","http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg"]

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
$str = '["http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg",
"http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg"]';
eval("\$myarray = $str;");
print_r($myarray);
```

Comment: Thank You Sir Now it's Working Thanks a lot... !!

Comment: Why with `eval()`? eval should never be used if there is another solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @if(json_decode($data->item_image) != '')
                                    @php $image = json_decode($data->item_image);
                                            eval("\$myarray = $image;");
                                    @endphp
                                            @foreach($myarray as $key=>$row)
                                                @if($key == 0)
                                                <div class='carousel-item active'>
                                                    <!-- <img class='img-size img-responsive' src="{{ asset('image/'. $row) }}" /> -->
                                                    <img class='img-size img-responsive' src="{{ $row }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                @else
                                                <div class='carousel-item'>
                                                    <!-- <img class='img-size' src="{{ asset('image/'. $row) }}" /> -->
                                                    <img class='img-size' src="{{ $row }}" />
                                                </div>
                                                @endif
                                            @endforeach
                                    @else

                                    @endif
```

Comment: 99,99% of the time `eval()` is not needed to solve a problem. In this case it is not needed, so don't use it.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative for eval() in this case ?

Comment: Json decode comes with a second parameter "associative", so `json_decode($data->item_image, true)` might give the array. If that doen't work, you can explode the string. I personally never needed to use `eval()` because there was always another (so better) way.

Comment: @GertB After Exploding it'll give output like Array = ( [0] => ["http://localhost//image/aeefb050911334869a7a5d9e4d0e1689.jpg" [1] => "http://localhost//image/959776b99b006e5785c3a3364949ce47.jpg"] )But this is Not i want

Comment: Well, what if I would add php code in the database column, `eval()` will run it. thats a big security risk.

Comment: Okay then I'll Find An alternative then if Any progress i'll update here

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).